# Should [botany] and [botanics] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Is there any significant difference between the terms of [botany](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botany) and [botanics](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botanics)? There are two tags for these two terms with a couple of questions tagged with each.

The questions "What kind of Dieffenbachia is this?" with [botanics](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botanics) and "Can you identify this blooming plant?" with [botany](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botany) seems quite overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word botanics seems to be used in different contexts.

1. as a synonym for Botany, the study of plants.  [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Botanics)
2. The singular word, botanic, is considered an adjective of botany by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botanic)
3. botanical is defined as "a substance obtained or derived from a plant" by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/botanical#other-words)

English being such a malleable language I believe that it is acquiring a new context as a short form of botanicals.  [Boots](https://www.boots.com/botanics), the English drugstore, has a line of plant based products and there are other retailers trying to capitalize on this.

Given that none of the questions tagged as botanics use this context I have merged botanics and botany. The tool for this indicates that

> Remember that caching of question lists may make it look like the tag
> still exists after the merge, but it doesn't!